# How can I measure the speed of a network drive mounted on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, filesystems, speed

Are there any tools to measure the speed of a network drive mounted on Windows 7?

I found a tool called [HD Tach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_Tach) but it's not compatible with Windows 7, and it does not look like it can measure network drives.

Comment: What do you mean by "network drives"?  Are you trying to determine drive speed, or network speed?

Comment: @techie007, I mean effective speed; treating the drive like a black box, as if I didn't know what type of storage device it was.

Comment: Can you just run HD Tach in compatibility mode, or is that out of the question?

Comment: What he wants to do is benchmark the network drive he has mapped. He wants to have the effective speed this network drive has (including network speed, drive speed on the remote computer, etc).

Comment: @johnthexiii, yes, I did try running `HD Tach` in compatibility mode, and the application opened, but it did **not** see my network drives, nor some of my other external drives.

Answer (score 1):

I use a network meter gadget on windows 7. It gives a lot of live informations (current download/upload speed, amount downloaded/uploaded this session and totally, etc..)
You can find it here : http://addgadget.com/network_meter/

You may have to configure it and tell him wich network adapter it will monitor.

Comment: If you want to test max speed, choose the right interface and start a file transfer. It'll show you the maximum speed it can send/receive.